# Having trouble upgrading Linux kernel in Xenial

Tags: kernel, 16.04

I have downloaded the latest kernel and headers but Ubuntu is not using it on reboot. Only 3.19.0-22 is working, when I choose one in the Grub menu.

Can I somehow refresh that list or force Ubuntu to choose the new Kernel (linux-image-4.6.2-040602-generic)

Here is a list of installed images and headers:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-3.19.8-992                             3.19.8-992.201605312242                             all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.8
ii  linux-headers-3.19.8-992-generic                     3.19.8-992.201605312242                             amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.8 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.6.2-040602                           4.6.2-040602.201606100516                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.6.2
ii  linux-headers-4.6.2-040602-generic                   4.6.2-040602.201606100516                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.6.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP

$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-18-generic                        3.19.0-18.18                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic                        3.19.0-21.21                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic                        3.19.0-22.22                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.6.2-040602-generic                     4.6.2-040602.201606100516                           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.6.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic                  3.19.0-18.18                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-21-generic                  3.19.0-21.21                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-22-generic                  3.19.0-22.22                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

$ uname -r
3.19.0-22-generic
```

I hope someone can help me

// Ulrik McArdle

UPDATE:

Output of sudo update-grub:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.2-040602-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-22-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.2-040602-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-22-generic
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

UPDATE 2:

Here an image of my Grub when I'm booting up:
[My Grub when booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N9go.jpg)

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

I reinstalled the Grub bootloader:

```
# purge old and reinstall new to sda
sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: At the grub menu, if you choose `Advanced options` is there any boot option with kernel 4.6.2?

Comment: How did you install them? Can you run **sudo update-grub** and reboot the machine and check the available kernel list in grub menu?

Comment: No I cannot see it or choose any other.

Comment: @bensen I installed it by downloading these files: 

linux-headers-4.6.2-040602_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_all.deb
linux-headers-4.6.2-040602-generic_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_amd64.deb
linux-image-4.6.2-040602-generic_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_amd64.deb

And then running: sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: I didn't check but 4.6 version should be in the official repo. Isn't it possible to install them using apt-get instead of installing a deb package?

Comment: Only 4.4.0-24 is in the repo, if I do a apt-cache search linux-image or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay as mentioned in my post the final answer was to reinstall Grub:

```
# purge old and reinstall new to sda
sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo mv /boot/grub /boot/grub_backup
sudo mkdir /boot/grub
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload grub. Usually, this problem happens automatically when you install a new kernel, so how did you install the kernel?
To update grub, use this command.

```
sudo update-grub
```

And then restart your computer.

Comment: I tried to update grub but it did not work.

Comment: Please post the output of the command.

Comment: See update - it looks like it found it alright

Comment: You should use **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade** instead of downloading the kernel and using dpkg -I. Because dpkg will not automatically update grub.

Comment: I did that when I upgraded to Xenial but my Kernel did not upgrade with it,  so I tried to it manually, sadly it didn't work.

Comment: How are you sure if didn't work? Did you restart your computer

Comment: Yes... I upgraded some time ago and I have just installed the new Kernel today. My computer has been turn off and on some times since :)

Comment: Yes but did you restart your computer after you updated grub.

Comment: Yes, I did. I also took a screenshot of the Grub, see update 2. I uninstalled the 4.6.* and installed the 4.4.* with apt-get install but no difference. In the screenshot you can see that it is not visible and it is still showing the old kernel which is not bootable.

Comment: Your kernel will not show up in the advanced tab. The newest kernel automatically replaces the Ubuntu option on the main grub page. If you highlight Ubuntu on the main page on the main page, and press tab. You should see your kernel after the vmlinuz option.

Comment: I have solved the problem by reinstalling Grub